# Hot re-deployment of a RESTlet

Tags: restlet

I'm interested in setting up a super lightweight web server with Restlet mostly for proofs-of-concept and low impedance collaboration with other developers. A full servlet container feels too heavy. Literally, I'm starting with something pulled directly from the "Getting Started" guide.

```
public class Dummy extends ServerResource {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Server(Protocol.HTTP, 8182, Dummy.class).start();
    }

    @Get("json")
    public String hello() {
        ST hello = new ST();
        hello.add("name", "World");
        return "{ \"hello\": \"World\"}";
    }

}
```

However, I'd like to be able to watch for changes and redeploy automatically as I change code. I know Jetty can do this with some config. Has anyone done this without setting up a full servlet container? Is there something simpler?

I use Eclipse as my IDE to edit the code and launch the app, but the ideal solution wouldn't rely on that.

Answer (score 0):

This what I call Continuous Delivery. 
In a nutshell:
I usually use

- SVN or Git to store and version source code
- Jenkins to schedule the build and deployment
- Gradle or Maven to build and test

The SCM plugin is able to poll the repository and invoke the process only if there is changes, or you can trigger the build with a hook.
There are plugins to copy your artifact to the target server and restart the application.